# asp.net webservice how to make compatible with PHP and other languages

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I am currently creating a web service in vb.net and I would like to ask the community what is the best way to make this compatible for PHP users and other languages.

An example of my code is as follows:

```
Public Shared Function GetBasketInfo(ByVal sessionid As String, ByRef ds As DataSet, ByVal attributes     

As String) As DataRow

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(attributes) Then
  Throw New ArgumentNullException("Please supply a manufacturer")
End If

Dim l As New List(Of String)

l = _serializer.SplitAttributes(attributes)


Dim s As String
Dim p(1) As SqlParameter
Dim dt As DataTable

's = "exec MSLStore1_GetOrderInfo @userid, @orderid"


dt = ExecuteDataTableDT("MSLStore1_GetOrderInfo", _
                     New SqlParameter("@userid", StoI(l(0))), _
                       New SqlParameter("@orderid", StoI(l(1)))
                     )



  Return dt.Rows(0)

   End Function
```

My question is will this method be compatible with PHP consumption. 
If not can someone point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this can be found here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/887892.aspx/1

More importantly the last posting, you would consume your ASP.NET web service by saving the .wdsl file (web service) and doing the following in PHP:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/csharp/web_service.asmx?wsdl");

print_r( $client->Add(array("a" => "5", "b" =>"2")));
```

Comment: another question is can php users consume data set's ok im written the web service in vb.net and want it accessable to as many developers as possible

Comment: Yep - you can write a Web Service in any language to be consumed by any other language. That's the entire beauty of Web Services as data is sent over SOAP :)

Comment: so i dont need to worry about sending back as xml for php they can consume a datasource when i run wsdl? at the end of my webservice it doesnt gererate anything on screen or a file im running vista and iis6

Comment: See this link:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/net-web-services-5-steps

You can do exactly what you've done, but you need to assign it as a web method. Check the code block at the bottom of the first page. Then it's just using the other steps to make this into a consumable web service.

Comment: its ok i had to view it in ie see the description so if say  can you proivide an example of how a php[ developer would pass a dataset so i can included it in my documentation

Comment: They wouldn't receive the data as a DataSet from another language, that's the whole idea. They recieve the data as XML from the Web Service and then convert that XML into their own business objects with whichever language they're using. 

My original answer shows how this would be done with PHP consuming an .asmx file.

Comment: many thanks im taking over a project from a previous developer and he does have data comming back as xml thanks for the help

Comment: Even though there should never be problems, I encountered one: PHP SOAP server, .NET client. They couldn't use our service because they only supported a special subset of SOAP, which does not include the equivalent of PHP key-value arrays.